# Is it possible to add a section with some informtion in browser using crossrider?

Tags: toolbar, browser-extension, crossrider

I am trying to develop an extension which will show some information(about 15 words) in a small section below the extensions icons in the browser using crossrider?. I searched about it and it seems that browser only supports extensions icons and bookmarks. So is it possible to add such kind of section?? Im new to browser extension development and not sure about its possibility.

Comment: Please can you clarify what you mean by showing some information below the extension icons. Which icons are you referring to? Where do they appear in the browser?

Comment: Im referring the right side of address bar. But if it is possible to add anywhere around address bar, it will be ok. Basically i will be showing IP to user with my website's tag below the IP. So anywhere around address bar will be fine. Is it possible Shlomo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nearest you can get to this is to use a browser action/button and use the tooltip (a.k.a. title) to display the information when the mouse hovers over the button. For example, in your *background.js* file your code would look something like:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('icons/icon.jpg');
  appAPI.browserAction.setTitle('Information displayed on mouse hover');
  appAPI.browserAction.onClick(function() {
    alert('Hello world!');
  });
});
```

For more information, see [appAPI.browserAction](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction).

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: OK this means what i am exactly looking for is not supported by browsers so i should go for other options. And yes i have already tested the solution you provided. Thanks for the response Sholomo.